# matlab2tikz error plotting image with alphadata

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, tikz

I am plotting a matrix ("I1") which has some NaN values through imagesc command. As you can see in the code I have set that such NaN values should be plotted in white

```
I = magic(10);
I1 = NaN(10);
I1(4:6,4:6) = I(4:6,4:6);
f1 = figure();
h = imagesc(I1);
colormap jet;
set(h,'alphadata',~isnan(I1))
axis tight;
axis equal;
axis on;
matlab2tikz('file.tex')
```

I need to convert such image in matlab2tikz (see indeed last line of the script) but I obtain the following error:

Error using writepng>parseInputs (line 349)
The value of 'alpha' is invalid. Expected input to be one of these types:double, uint8, uint16

Instead its type was logical.

Can someone help to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: NaN is not any of those types that can be plotted, which is why plotting it won't work. Try going around this problem by replacing the values for NaN with some number or something like that.

Comment: @jmoon `NaN` can be used for plotting.  It simply does not plot the point and it's quite often used. However, it is not valid for alpha data which I believe what you are referring to - not actually the plotting of the data but the assigning of a transparency value for each point in the image.

Comment: Sorry, was unclear in my comment. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: How can assign a trasparency value such that it will be accepted by matlab2tikz function?

Comment: @rayryeng the error is in the matlab2tikz conversion, so it seems that NaN is valid for alpha data

Comment: @Quo It is not and I disagree.  Nowhere in MATLAB's graphical system should it ever accept `NaN` for transparency data.  It absolutely does not make sense.  Also, the error messages that MATLAB gives you are quite specific.  There are no hidden messages and it's quite black and white.  It is not commenting on the fact that the data consists of `NaN`, it's the fact that it's type `logical`.  All you have to do is change the type to one of `double, uint8` or `uint16`.  Given the nature of your array, you should convert it to `double`.  I've made an answer for you below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is convert your the transparencies into `double`.  Right now, the array is of type `logical` and transparency data can only be one of `double, uint8` or `uint16`.  Given the nature of your array, you want anything that is non `NaN` to be fully visible while values that are `NaN` to be transparent, so you want `0/1` data, not `true/false`.

Simply convert to `double` after the fact:

```
set(h,'alphadata',double(~isnan(I1)));
```